# Date check is not working to show error if End Date is less than Start Date

Tags: html, angular6, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-date-format

I am trying to add a check in my form to check if the End Date is less than the Starting Date it should throw an error which is not working. Don't know whats the issue here.

my .html code is as follows:

```
<label class="col-md-2 form-control-label">Event Starting Date</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="validate" #startdate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="input.event_starting_date" name="startdate" type="date" placeholder="Event Starting Date" class="form-control" required>
     <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="startdate.touched && !startdate.valid">Starting Date is required!</div>                        
</div>

 <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label">Event Ending Date</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <input class="validate" #enddate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="input.event_ending_date" name="enddate" type="date" placeholder="Event Ending Date" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="enddate.touched && !enddate.valid">Ending Date is required!</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="enddate<startdate">Ending Date Must be greater than Starting Date!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The end- and startdate are put in a model like this:

```js
date = {
    year: '',
    month: '',
    day: ''
  };
```

Have you tried comparing every different property of both date models? I don't think you can compare both models directly to each other since they both have their own underlying properties.